# Did Weyland-Yutani learn the location of the derelict on LV-426 from Ripley?

Tags: aliens, aliens-1986

I've always assumed that Weyland-Yutani executives learned the approximate location of the derelict from the flight recorder on the Nostromo's escape pod after Ripley was rescued. I've also assumed from the dialogue between Burke and Ripley toward the end of *Aliens* that Burke secretly contacted someone at Hadleys Hope, who then ordered Newt's parents to investigate the location where the Nostromo landed, causing them to discover the derelict, is that correct? If they had already known the derelict's location, I assume they would have had someone investigate it prior to the events of *Aliens*.

Answer (score 5):

Burke had the flight recorder tampered with, prior to Ripley's board of enquiry. He got the coordinates for the derelict ship (and a brief description of the alien eggs that it carried and the alien life-form) from the black box which included Ripley's log entries.  He ordered the head of Hadley's Hope to investigate the coordinates of the crashed alien ship. The colony leader then send Newt's parents out to investigate.

> *"You heard me. The colonists. All those poor, unsuspecting good Company people. Like Newt’s family. You said I’d been doing my homework, remember? You sent them to that ship, to check out the alien derelict. I just checked it out in the colony log. It’s as intact as the plans Hudson called up. Would make interesting reading in court. ‘Company Directive Six Twelve Nine, dated five thirteen seventy-nine. Proceed to inspect possible electromagnetic emission at coordinates-but I’m not telling you anything you don’t already know, am I? Signed Burke, Carter J."* She was trembling with anger. It was all spilling out of her at once, the frustration and fury at the incompetence and greed that had brought her back to this world of horror.
>
> *"You sent them out there, and you didn’t even warn them, Burke. You sat through the inquest. You heard my story. Even if you didn’t believe everything, you must have believed enough of it to want the coordinates checked out. You must have thought there was something to it or you wouldn’t have gone to the trouble of having anyone go out there to look around. Out to the alien ship. You might not have believed, but you suspected."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Aliens: Official Novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Aliens_(novel))</sup></sub>

Ripley point-blank accuses him of mucking with the recorder. He doesn't bother to deny it.

> *"Look, maybe the thing didn’t even exist, right? Maybe there wasn’t
> much to it. All we had to go on was your story, which was a bit much
> to take at face value."*
>
> *"Was it? The Narcissus’s recorder was tampered with, Burke. Remember me
> telling the board of inquiry about that? You wouldn’t happen to know
> what happened to the recorder, would you?”*
>
> He ignored the question.

Comment: **RIPLEY:** *...I'm telling you those
                    things exist.  Back on that planetoid
                    is an alien ship and on that ship
                    are thousands of eggs.  Thousands.
                    Do you understand?  I suggest you
                    find it, using the flight recorder's
                    data.  Find it and deal with it --
                    before one of your survey teams
                    comes back with a little surprise...* - [Script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Aliens_James_Cameron_May_28_1985_first_draft.html)